# Comparing records from two columns with unequal lengths

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing validation of two columns(with unequal lengths) present on two different sheets of excel.

The first sheet name is 'Task'. Column 'A' of the 'Task' sheet has about 200 City Names.

The second sheet is 'Cities'. Column 'A' of the 'Cities' sheet has about 8000+ City Names.

Now I need to do validation such that the name of City in Column A of 'Task' sheet should be

1. Either one among the City Names specified in column 'A' of sheet 'Cities'
2. Or It can have multiple entries separated with semicolon; after separating all cities based on semicolon each city names shall match with that one in column D of 'Cities' sheet.
3. If not among both the above cases then it should be '**All**'

The cells in 'Task' Sheet from which City names do not match are to be turned in Red background

My Code is as follows: (am just giving required part of code)

```
Dim CityString As String
Dim CityArray() As String

'Get the last row
'Dim lastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Variant

'Turn screen updating off to speed up macro code.
'User won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In Worksheets("Task").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
CityString = c
CityArray() = Split(CityString, ";")
For Each e In CityArray()
e = Trim(e)
    For Each d In Worksheets("Cities").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
        c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    
        If (UCase(e) = UCase(d) Or c = "All") Then
        c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If c.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
    Exit For
    End If
Next
Next
```

Now, the above code is valid only when both the sheets (Sheet1 - 'Task' and Sheet2 - 'Cities' have equal number of records. If Sheet2 - 'Cities' has more records than the 'Task' Sheet, the above code do not work.

For Example: New York is at 'A55' Cell of 'Task' sheet.
It's also there in 'Cities' Sheet at 'A41'. My code validates the cell correctly.

For Example: 'A53' of 'Task' sheet I have 'Tokyo' and 'Task' Sheet has only 200 records, where as 'Tokyo' is present at 'A988' of 'Cities' sheet, which has some 8000+ records, then my code does not validate this cell correctly.

Can it be done in better way ?

Comment: I would break this project into a few smaller steps: (1) Transform the "Cities" sheet into a single column of city names, meaning all semicolon-delimited cells have been parsed out and each cell contains exactly one city name. (2) Loop through the "Cities" column of city names, searching for a match on the "Task" sheet. (3) Apply formatting based on whether or not a match is found

Comment: @DanWagner Oh... Buddy Thanks for the reply... I have presented only small portion of the code. My both the sheets have 30+ columns each. among those one is 'Cities' and my this question is related to the other question I have asked on stackoverflow.com. Can you see into that also. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045505/how-to-validate-hierarchy-of-three-columns-in-excel-vba) I have already written the code as u have suggested. But I need a code which shall work in the case where 'Cities' sheet has less records than 'Task'(If am applying the logic explained above) Or viceversa

Comment: @DanWagner
As I have some 40 other types of validations in excelsheet; again breaking the logic into smaller steps going lower performance :(

Comment: It looks like you need to redefine the `LastRow' variable to be used with the Cities sheet. It uses the previously declared LastRow value from the tasks sheet. [Personal Preference]: I sometimes use different variables when I'm identifying the last row for two different sheets. This reduces my confusion. EDIT: Looks like you will need to use two different variables since both sheet's last rows are being referenced concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very efficient to loop through a list of values searching for a match. The longer each of the lists becomes, the longer it will take to run the macro. Instead, use the built-in *FIND* method to search for values.

I've updated the code to show the FIND method in action. Check it out and let me know if this makes sense/works.

(SIDE NOTE): I left a comment above detailing why your initial code wasn't working correctly. You needed a second variable to reference the last row of the cities sheet.

```
Dim CityString As String
Dim CityArray() As String

'Get the last row
'Dim lastRow As Integer
LastRow = Sheets("Task").UsedRange.Rows.Count
nLastRowSheet2 = Sheets("Cities").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Variant

'Turn screen updating off to speed up macro code.
'User won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In Worksheets("Task").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    CityString = c
    CityArray() = Split(CityString, ";")
    For Each e In CityArray()
        e = Trim(e)

        Dim rngFnder As Range
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnder = Sheets("Cities").Range("A2:A" & nLastRowSheet2).Find(e)

            If rngFnder Is Nothing Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
Next
```